# regex Illegal repetition

Tags: java

I have a string array of operators that I am iterating through.  When I find one that exists in `strLine`, I replace the first instance of it with a blank string.  When I get to the `{`, I get the `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`.

Now, I know that the `{` is a special java operator so that is the reason it is failing.  What would be the best way to escape this character with the setup I have now?

```
String[] operators = {".", ",", "{", "}", "!", "++", "--", "*", "/", "%", "+", "-", "<"}

String strLine = "for (int count = input.length(); count > 0; count--) {";
strLine = strLine.trim();

for (int i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
    if(strLine.contains(operators[i])) {

        strLine = strLine.replaceFirst(operators[i]+"\\s*", "");
        System.out.println("Removal of: " + operators[i]);
        System.out.println("Sentence after removal: " + strLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `replace` instead of `replaceFirst`?

Comment: I can have multiple things to replace.  I don't have it working properly yet, but I'll have to loop through the operators more than once if there are still some in there by the time it finishes the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should able to escape the special character using java.util.regex.Pattern.quote

By changing

```
strLine = strLine.replaceFirst(operators[i]+"\\s*", "");
```

to

```
strLine = strLine.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(operators[i])+"\\s*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape each regex reserved operator with a backslash. So you need to put two backslashes (the other one is to escape the backslash itself). Example: "\\.", "\\{"